# How to (temporarily) store Eloquent models in DB without a proper schema?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model whose schema I know will change rapidly during development, so I don't want to create a proper schema for it right now, I'll do it later. But I'd still like to be able to save items in storage.

Example for clarification: I have an Article model, which now has some attributes, but I'll later add many more and I don't want to add a column for every such modification. I'd just like to save it in storage.

Maybe some kind of serialization? Even Cache would be okay, if it could work: it can save, but I can't retrieve all articles easily, cause I don't know the exact keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a schema-less storage, like MongoDB. It's kindof made for a scenario like you describe. If you decide to use a traditional relational database later, worry about the migration at that time.